# Firebase transactions data

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm using firebase for a game. Working with transactions and I'm getting a "object has no method 'val'" error.

It's annoying that their docs only have currentvalue+1 examples and not more complex.

With the game each player has x number of mins to submit the score. Naturally some scores will be submitted at the same time.

here's my script

```
var myScore=15;
var scoreRef = new Firebase('https://site.firebaseIO.com/arcade/games/keys/'+key+'/bonsai/'+bonsaiGameID+'/');
scoreRef.transaction(function(snapshot) {
    var leaderScore=snapshot.val().score;
    var leaderID=snapshot.val().leaderID; 
    if(myscore>leaderScore){
        scoreRef.push({data}) 
})
```

So 1st get the current score, if my score is higher push.

Comment: fixing the object has no val problem

Comment: i think snapshot IS the value according to https://www.firebase.com/docs/transactions.html ".transaction(" is used differently than ".once("

Comment: Yeah I saw that, let me try it a different way. I thought they'd have transactions on their leaderboard example

Comment: @dandavis: you might want to provide your comment as an answer. Otherwise this question will likely be closed as a "simple typographical error".

Comment: as long as dude got helped i'm ok with that, this doesn't need to be one for posterity...

Answer (score 1):

A transaction is not passed snapshot, but rather the value itself. The value can be a primitive (boolean, string or number) but can also be an object. It is basically the result of snapshot.val() rather than the snapshot itself.